# A simple question of density in $l^1$ (sequence space)

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

I need to show that the linear span of $S=\{e_n|n≥1\}$, where $e_n = (\delta_{nj})_{j≥1}$ is dense in $l^1$.

I know I'm doing something wrong here, but why can't I make a sequence of sequences in sp{$S$} such as

$1,0,0,0,0,\dots$

$1,1,0,0,0, \dots$

$1,1,1,0,0,\dots$

etc.

whose limit is clearly not in $l^1$?

How would I then go about showing the answer to the question?

Comment: That sequence is not Cauchy in the $\ell^1$-norm, so *it does not converge* in any normed sup-space of $\ell^1$.

Comment: And, by the way, your example cannot disprove density. Density is an extrinsic property. A topological subspace is dense *in an ambient space*. For instance, $\Bbb Q$ is dense in the subspace of algebraic real numbers, even if there are Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$ which converge to a trascendental number. $\Bbb Q$ is dense in the set of algebraic real numbers because you can approximate any algebraic real number by a sequence of rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=(\xi_k)\in \ell_1$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then you will find $N$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^\infty |\xi_k| < \varepsilon$ for $n\geqslant N$. Let $y = (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_N, 0,0,\ldots)$. Certainly, $y$ is in the span of $e_1, \ldots, e_N$. Moreover

$$\|x-y\|_{\ell_1} = \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |\xi_k|<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Why should this be a contradiction? In the same manner, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, while the sequence $a_n = n$ of rational numbers does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$.

To solve the problem, you need to show that every sequence in $l^1$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by a sequence in $\langle S \rangle$. You just need to truncate the sequence you want to approximate after sufficiently many elements.

Comment: Okay, I get your first point. But I don't understand how showing that every sequence in $l^1$ can be approximated by one in sp{$S$} shows that the closure of sp{$S$} $=l^1$. My idea was to show that all the limit points of sp{$S$} were in $l^1$. How is this equivalent to your approximation method?

Comment: Both statements are equivalent. Note that $x$ is a limit point of a sequence in $M$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find an element $m \in M$ with $\|x - m \| \le \varepsilon$. Also, note that you don't need to show that all limit points lie in $l^1$ (this holds by definition), but rather that every point of $l^1$ is a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(\alpha_k) \in l^1$. Then $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_ke_k$, since, with $x_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_ke_k$, we have

$$||x_n-x||_{l^1} \to 0.$$

Thus $x \in \overline{S}$